# What is the Fast Fourier Transform?

Tags: algorithm, math, fft

I was asked an interview question where I needed to use it but I have no idea what it is.
So in plain english what is the [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) and how can I use it to find the derivative of a function given its (x, y) values as input?

How would you implement it?

EDIT:
I am asking this because given a sequence of (x, y) values I needed to calculate how the function looks like, derive it and find the number of times it is constantly changing (that is, (0, 1), (1, 2) is counted as one) or does not change at all (0, 5), (1, 5) is also counted as one change).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Just curious, who asked a question like that? Did you apply for a math heavy position without knowing what FFT is, or did you apply for a "normal" job and they asked you this?

Comment: @erikkallen: I applied to a normal job and they asked a question where the only viable solution I could think of is to find the derivative of a function to find for how many points the function has no change in values, is constantly raising in values or constantly decreasing in values.

Comment: @erikkallen In jobs involving DSP, you're expected to know FFT.

Comment: @Nishant: I'm not sure if my job would have involved DSP. See edit.

Comment: If that was the question, I would just sort the values by x and then do a pairwise compare of them. Using FFT seems like overkill, hard to do and even harder to maintain for the next poor soul who has never heard of it.

Comment: @Nishant: Jobs involving DSP would count as math heavy IMO.

Comment: @the_drow sounds like edge detection to me http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection#Differential_edge_detection If I recall correctly, you can achieve using FFT as well

Comment: @erikkallen yes, they are. jump to web-dev :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have used google, however the math is too high for me. I'm only 21 and I still haven't started my BA. If everyone here told the OP to use google stackoverflow wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Nishant: That's also not a simple algorithm or I need to think more about it.

Comment: @the_drow If you can't understand the maths when you read the results of web searches, why would Stack Overflow be able to teach you it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Because as you can see from the answers. It gives me something to start with.

Comment: @the_drow As a basic courtesy you should pre-empt such responses as I gave by indicating that you had done some research and what you failed to understand as a result of that. Not only will that show that you were prepared to put some effort in yourself, it will likely result in more applicable help being given. There are a lot of people here that ask questions without doing even the most cursory web search. It seems you aren't in that category, but please let us know.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY) a video that explains the idea of a Fourier Transform really well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for the first part of the question, a former Physics professor, Bartosz Milewski, has a very nice [explanation](http://relisoft.com/Science/Physics/sound.html), what FFT is and how it works.

Also, [Mastering The Fourier Transform in One Day](http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/dft-a-pied/) is worth reading as well.

### In English (?)

Say you have a sound coming from the speaker.

You then set up, let's get a nice round number here, 1024 harmonic oscillators that resonate to specific frequency ranges.

Play the sound for, say, a second.

Oscillators begin to resonate to the sound coming from the speaker. After the said second you read how much every oscillator is resonating. As a result you get a discrete fourier transform, meaning you get a chart of how much each of the frequency ranges contributed to the sound coming from the speaker.

Instead of visualising the sound as amount of air pressure caused by the waveform, changing in time slots, you visualized it as a series of intensities of the frequency ranges.

Of course in explaining the DFT, the speakers part is not really appropriate since you have to work on sampled input. So in this case the 1024 digital "oscillators" should actually be measured after 1/44th of a second, given the audio is sampled at the rate of 44kHz.

Fast Fourier Transform is an algorithm to perform a Discrete Fourier Transform that's pretty easy for computers to run on an incoming signal. It imposes some constraints you have to work with in your implementation (e.g. the number of samples has to be a power of 2), because it uses some clever tricks to drastically reduce the amount of calculation performed on the sample buffer.

There is really no need to go deeper, since the two links I gave provide a pretty clear explanation. And note that it's impossible to go from theory to implementation without knowing the math behind it.

I hope this introduction makes some sense!

Comment: It does. You should actually edit the wiki page to provide an example.

Comment: FYI: Your links are swapped (Also, I think 1/44th should be 1/44000, no?)

Comment: Of course, it's 1/44000. Thanks for both tips! Wait, on second thought, no, that's correct - 1/44th of a second, since we're taking 1024 samples. When sampling at 44kHz then, we'll have 44 of such fourier transforms in one second.

Answer (score 7):

Fourier analysis is a family of mathematical techniques, all based on decomposing signals into sinusoids. The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is the family member used with digitized signals.

From Wolfram,

> The fast Fourier transform (FFT) is a discrete Fourier transform algorithm which reduces the number of computations needed for N points from 2N^2 to 2NlgN, where lg is the base-2 logarithm. If the function to be transformed is not harmonically related to the sampling frequency, the response of an FFT looks like a sinc function (although the integrated power is still correct). Aliasing (also known as leakage) can be reduced by apodization using an apodization function. However, aliasing reduction is at the expense of broadening the spectral response.

It's usually taught as a part of Signal Processing courses. So, you must have been needing to work on some image/sound processing. :)

See these lectures from Stanford Engineering: [here](http://academicearth.org/courses/the-fourier-transform-and-its-applications)

Basically, DFT is

[image]

And Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm's pseudo code is as follows:

```
Y0,...,N−1 ← ditfft2(X, N, s):             DFT of (X0, Xs, X2s, ..., X(N-1)s):
    if N = 1 then
        Y0 ← X0                                      trivial size-1 DFT base case
    else
        Y0,...,N/2−1 ← ditfft2(X, N/2, 2s)             DFT of (X0, X2s, X4s, ...)
        YN/2,...,N−1 ← ditfft2(X+s, N/2, 2s)           DFT of (Xs, Xs+2s, Xs+4s, ...)
        for k = 0 to N/2−1                           combine DFTs of two halves into full DFT:
            t ← Yk
            Yk ← t + exp(−2πi k/N) Yk+N/2
            Yk+N/2 ← t − exp(−2πi k/N) Yk+N/2
        endfor
    endif
```

(Shamelessly copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm)

Also, you may wanted to look into

1. http://www.fftw.org/download.html
2. http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3457251
3. http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm

Comment: The problem with "I don't get it" replies from the original poster is that it might be shorthand for "It doesn't matter how well-written the answer is; I don't have the mathematical background to understand it."

Comment: @duffymo agree. It's called "curse of knowledge". When you know something, you can't understand what not-knowing is. And that's why good teachers are rare gift. :)

Comment: I agree, but the best teacher in the world won't be able to bridge the gap between a high school math background and FFT.  Even your fine answer won't do it.

Comment: @duffymo since I have a HS math background ending with pre-calc and I don't know what topics I might need to know to reach an understanding, could you please list the minimum topics I need to know to understand it? Thanks!

Comment: Sure: algebra, trigonometry and calculus should do it.

Answer (score 6):

The fast Fourier transform (FFT) is an algorithm for calculating the [discrete Fourier transform](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) (DFT). You could think of the DFT as a way of representing a sampled signal as a sum of sinusoids. Since the derivative of a sine is simple, you can estimate the derivative of a signal sample by finding the derivative of its DFT.

This is a large topic in [signal processing](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Signal_processing), and I recommend buying an introductory book or taking a course to learn more.

**Update**: In plainer English, it's a way of looking at a sequence of numbers as a sum of waves.

Comment: This still tells me nothing at all. In plain English.

Comment: So basically it would generate a function that I could derive. Hmm interesting.

Comment: @the_drow: Yes. Since you can't derive "loose" values, the DFT "guesses" what happens between those points. That gives you a function that you can derive.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest explanation I can think of: Given a .wav file containing a tone, FFT could tell you the frequency of that tone. But it can also be used for more interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

this might solve your problem:
[Fast Fourier transform on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)

They even have links to implemented algorithms.

Basically it's a way to do a Fourier Tranform numerically, which allows a computer to do it.

Comment: I already read the wikipedia value without understanding it.